# Текстовая RPG игра на Ruby

Tags: ruby

Я абсолютный ноль в программировании, и не так давно, я начал изучать язык Ruby. И мне в голову пришли идея сделать (чисто для себя и друзей) игру, которая имеет свой сюжет, диалоги с вариантами ответов и разумеется несколько концовок. Всё будет работать в консоли через обычный текст. На что-то серьёзное я к сожалению пока не способен.

Так вот в чём проблема. Я хочу иметь несколько сюжетных линий. В зависимости от ответа игрока, будет зависеть по какой сюжетной ветке будет идти игрок. Всё это я хотел реализовать с помощью разбивки всего сюжета на файлы, и при выборе ответа с помощью цифр, происходила загрузка следующего файла: к примеру

```
puts "СЦЕНАРИЙ"

puts "Для выбора действия нажмите 1, 2 или 3"

user_input = nil
user_input = STDIN.gets.chomp

if user_input == "1"
    load "./сюжетная_линия1.rb"

elsif user_input == "2"
    load "./сюжетная_линия2.rb"

else user_input == "3"
    load "./сюжетная_линия3.rb"

end
```

Или для красоты IF...ELSE...END можно поместить в метод.

Так вот. Этих файлов с сюжетной линией может быть овер 100500. И все они конечно же называться одинаково не могут. В голову приходит мысль всё раскидывать по папкам. Но тогда идея с методом отпадает, потому что в этом случае придётся каждый раз поправлять директорию загрузки файла.

Или можно (или нужно) присваивать файлам уникальное имя, но ведь сама идея загрузки файлов зависет от того, что напишет игрок.

Скорей всего, я просто занимаюсь мазохизмом и есть более лаконичный способ это всё провернуть, просто я о нём ещё не знаю, так как нахожусь в процессе обучения.

Может подскажите какой нибудь алгоритм?

Comment: Сам студент, однако приходилось слышать о применении графов для реализации квестов в играх. Возможно Вам стоит разбить сюжетную линию на действия, реализуемые в качестве вершин, и связать их по своему усмотрению. Надеюсь, будет полезным.

Comment: Можно на файлы не разбивать

Comment: @Alex78191 Да, согласен, на файлы можно не разбивать, но тогда получится не одна тысяча строк диалогов в файле. Для меня это чревата просто запутаться во всей этой каше :D Разбивка на файлы мне показалось более удобным и более ориентированным способом. Так сказать чтобы знать, что куда идёт

Comment: Не легче использовать документоориентированную БД для хранения иерархического графа сюжета?

Comment: Вместо уникальных файлов нужно сделать структуру папкой с именами соответствующим сюжетным линиям и содержащим файл с одним и тем же названием file.rb

Comment: @Alex78191 Структуру папок если я правильно понял вы посоветовали делать уже в БД? Можете посоветовать какую БД мне использовать? Честно говоря я с этим ещё не сталкивался, и пока не могу представить как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: Много вопросов в игре?

Comment: Можно всю историю хранить в файле JSON

Comment: @Alex78191 Пока ограничиваюсь максимум тремя вариантами развилок. И большая часть вариантов это "последствия" выбора. То бишь  - "произошло то-то, то-то. Что будете делать дальше". Ну и всё в этом духе)

Comment: @Alex78191 развилок получилось просто тьма :D

Comment: какое количество развилок?

Comment: Я что-то так и не понял, а в чём проблема с текущим подходом? Топорно, конечно, но должно работать.

Comment: @Alex78191 примерно 70-80 уникальных историй :В

Comment: @D-side Согласен, текущий подходит будет работать, но хотелось как нибудь "удобнее" чтоли...